# How to move bookmarks across Google Chrome profiles

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

My Chrome browser just updated itslef over the network to version 40. This new version has a button on the right-hand-side of the title bar just to the left of the minimize/maximize/close buttons with the user's profile name written on it. Now I would like to switch to a different profile but retain my bookmarks. How do I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On your Chrome browser's address bar enter:

chrome://bookmarks

Then click on the Organize menu item and choose "Export bookmarks to HTML file..." and save the file on your somewhere on your hard drive such as on your desktop.

Then click on the profile switcher on the aforementioned button in the title bar, and then enter the  same chrome://bookmarks URL form your new profile this time choosing "Import bookmarks from HTML file...". Choose your exported bookmarks file and you're done.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer is correct, but you can also drag and drop bookmarks across two windows. This may be preferred if you don't wish to do a bulk export/import.

- Open browser windows for both profiles.
- Place the two windows side by side.
- Open chrome://bookmarks in each window.
- Drag and drop bookmarks between windows as desired (you can drag and drop to/from the bookmarks bar as well).

Comment: This answer s acceptable if you have a small handful of bookmarks. For those who have been using Chrome since it had single-digit version numbers, with 100s-1000s of bookmarks, the accepted answer is the way to go.

Comment: That's right, it's up to user preference. That being said, Chrome shouldn't have any problem handling thousands of bookmarks in the drag and drop.